# Accessing Dev Environment from another VM (Virtualbox)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

On my OSX machine I have two VM's running:

- Development Environment (aka DE) (Linux)
- Testing Environment (aka TE) (Win7 IE9)

In my TE, I would like to be able to access a server running on my DE. Pretty straight forward sounding but I'm sort of new.

I'm using Virtualbox as my client on both machines. My dev environment is a vagrant box setup with puppet. I can modify it with virtualbox as well for now. SIMPLEST solution wins. I have tried nested-boxing, it doesn't work :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired results much more easily than I had anticipated. I had to add the same lines I added to my local machine to my VM.